# How can I control image size in Flutter's CircleAvatar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this Dart code in a Flutter project;

```dart
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 130.0,
  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/image.jpg'),
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
)
```

The `radius` parameter seem to control the size of part of the image seen through the circle 'window', this obscures part of the image because the image size is still the same. The image is 567 * 572 pixel. How can I control the size of the image as well?

Comment: Can you attach an image

Comment: @HardikKumar, the image is approximately square, i can't share due to some regulations.

Comment: No worries, I've posted an answer, I hope it'll help you out.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `CircleAvatar`, use `Container` and make it circular, like this:

```
Container(
  width: 130,
  height: 130,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    image: DecorationImage(
      image:  AssetImage('assets/image.jpg'),
      fit: BoxFit.fill
    ),
  ),
)
```

**The output (ignore the blur in the background):**

[image]

Comment: Still the image is cropped, not resized.

Comment: Can you send the image you're trying to put inside the `CircleAvatar` OR the image similar to what you're trying to do

Comment: @Amani - you can play with the `fit`, try `fit: BoxFit.scaleDown`

Answer (score 0):

```
SizedBox(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  child: CircleAvatar(
    child: ClipOval(
      child: Image.network(photo),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

To control image size (**height and width**) in Flutter's CircleAvatar, do this:

```
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 20,
                        backgroundColor: Color(0XFFEEEEFF),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 15,
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                            ImageAssets.micIcon,
                          ),
                          backgroundColor: Color(0XFFEEEEFF),
                        ),
                      ),
```

**OR** this code must work:

```
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 20,
                        backgroundColor: Color(0XFFEEEEFF),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            color: Color(0XFFEEEEFF),
                          ),
                          child: Image.asset(
                            ImageAssets.micIcon,
                            height: height * 0.03,
                            width: width * 0.2,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
Image.asset(
  'assets/images.jpg',
   width: 300,
   height: 150,
   fit:BoxFit.fill  
),
```

Comment: I need to use CircleAvatar due to design specification.